# Определение языка пользователя через HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE для стран СНГ

Tags: php, html

Есть сайт на русском и английском. Язык определяется через заголовок `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`. Я правильно понимаю что для стран СНГ нужно выставлять русский? Или у них русские браузеры?

Comment: Браузер пошлёт наиболее предпочитаемые языки. Если локаль русская, то не важно что это из Украины пользователь.

Comment: @Other Я просто так язык беру: substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2); Т.е. не учитываю все эти приоритеты q.

Comment: Плохо. Приоритеты не для галочки там стоят. Плюс - может у Вас полученного языка нет? Лучше нормально распарсить заголовок, ранжировать его и действовать.

Comment: @Other Думаете у них (украинцы, беларусы, казахи) вторым по приоритету стоит русский? Ладно, придется заморочиться.

Comment: Языки выбираются из предпочтений, а не по национальному признаку.

Comment: @Other бррр... причём тут национальный признак? разумеется в данном контексте речь идёт только о языках.